# Regex match first word same as last word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here's the regex:

```
"'(\d{4})-(.*)-(\d{4})'i"
```

I want to match the first part of number (\d{4}) which must same as last part

Like this:

- 1111-abcdefg-2222 = invalid
- 1111-x-1111 = valid
- 0000-rwrgreheherhe-0000 = valid
- 1234-abcd-5678 -  invalid

how can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I use the following script to check the output

```
$i = '1111-abcd-1111';
preg_match("'(\d{4})-(.*)-(\1)'i",$i,$m);
echo print_r($m,true);
```

but return empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\1` as a backreference to your first capture group:

```
'~(\d{4})-(.*)-\1~'
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/2Jw0dL

Comment: thanks for fast reply,but seems not work,I print the $matches array but return empty

Comment: that's odds,I just changed `"` to `'` and it works,thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use a backreference:

```
'/(\d{4})-(.*)-\1/i'
```

`\1` equals to what you captured in the first capture group.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use back-reference:

```
"'(\d{4})-(.*)-\1'i"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("'(\d{4})-(.*)-(\g1)'i",$i,$m);
```

add the \g1 to the back reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php

> As of PHP 5.2.2, the \g escape sequence can be used for absolute and relative referencing of subpatterns. This escape sequence must be followed by an unsigned number or a negative number, optionally enclosed in braces. The sequences \1, \g1 and \g{1} are synonymous with one another. The use of this pattern with an unsigned number can help remove the ambiguity inherent when using digits following a backslash. The sequence helps to distinguish back references from octal characters and also makes it easier to have a back reference followed by a literal number, e.g. \g{2}1.

Comment: \\1 also seems to work. I think this is your use of double quotes causing problems.
preg_match('/(\d{4})-(.*)-(\1)/i',$i,$m);
works fine.